# JAXB Annotation for using child Elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I do marshaling and unmarshaling messages.
I have XML type like this:

```
@XMLAccesorType(AccesorType.FIELD)
@XMLType(name="Header")
public class Header{

@XMLElement(name="messageId")
private String messageId;
//getters and setters
}
```

and I have Messages type:

```
<Message>
<messageId>1111</messageId>
</Message>
```

I want to allocate MessageId type to independence class, because I use it a lot of time in different messages:

```
@XMLAccesorType(AccesorType.FIELD)
@XMLType(name="MessageIdType")
public class MessageIdClass{

@XMLElement(name="messageId")
private String messageId;
//getters and setters
}
```

But then I have unwanted tag that wrap MessageId.
I want:

```
<Message>
   <MessageId>1111</MessageId>
</Message>
```

But got:

```
<Message>
   <MessageIdType>
      <MessageId>1111</MessageId>
   </MessageIdType>
</Message>
```

Also Messages can not inheritance some base class with messageId field.
Can I write something like this?:

```
//inside Message
@SomeAnnotation(useOnlyChildFields=true)
MessageIdClass msgId;
```

Comment: Can you explain `But then I have unwanted tag that wrap MessageId.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
@XmlType(name="MessageIdType")
public class MessageIdClass{
    @XmlValue
    private String messageId;
}
```

This will create a simple type.

If you need more than one property, or if the one property you need cannot be mapped to a simple type, you can still create a type with several properties, and then use:

```
new JAXBElement<MessageIdClass>(
    new QName("http://foo/bar", "ElementOfThisType"),
    MessageIdClass.class,
    null,
    object_of_type_MessageIdClass);
```

to create elements of this type. This is typically done in the `ObjectFactory`, with a method that receives a `MessageIdClass` object, annotated with `@XmlElementDecl`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `@XmlValue` is what you are looking for, this will eliminate the `messageId` element:

```
@XmlAccesorType(XmlAccesorType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="MessageIdType")
public class MessageIdClass{

    @XmlValue
    private String messageId;
    //getters and setters
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html